# PHP header not redirecting, like its not there

Tags: php, session, header

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
$_SESSION = array();
header("Location: index.php");
} else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

I tried everything in the other stack overflow threads, nothing works.

This code used to work on my old host, so i'm thinking it is a configuration error?

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Is this code in `index.php` itself? You'll get a redirect loop error in most browsers. Also remember to `exit;` after a redirect to prevent any code after from executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) or [ob_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) at the top of your page.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For Header Location, use an url like:

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
```